# How to plot an unstacked table in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I have processed my data from a dataframe such that it is unstacked as follows:
[image]

The code that I used to reach to this level is as follows:

```
df_age_bins.groupby('Product')['age_bins'].value_counts().unstack()
```

I am struggling to go beyond this such that I can plot a bar graph with 'age_bins' on the x-axis, the count on the y-axis with each bar split three-way by Product (i.e. TM195, TM498, TM798).

Thanks for any advice/ help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can unstack `Product` instead and chain with `plot.bar()`:

```
(df_age_bins.groupby('Product')['age_bins']
     .value_counts().unstack('Product')
     .plot.bar(stacked=True)
)
```

Comment: Thank you this worked! Originally I had 'df_age_bins.groupby('Product')['age_bins'].value_counts().unstack().plot.bar()' and ws getting the following error *Buffer has wrong number of dimensions (expected 1, got 0)* - can you explain why yours worked and mine didn't?

Comment: @Ossz not sure why, it should still plots except that `Product` will be on the x-axis. Glad this solves your problem though.